# Возможно перевести код в рег. выражение Python?

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

```
def correct(s):
    mapping = str.maketrans({'0': 'O', '1': 'I', '5': 'S'})
    return s.translate(mapping)
   #return string.replace('1','I').replace('0','O').replace('5','S')

print(correct("51NGAP0RE")) #=="SINGAPORE"
```

Comment: Сделал вот так 3 строки: result = re.sub(r'5', 'S', s) возможно сделать 1ой строкой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, возможно. [re.sub](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) вторым аргументом принимает функцию, которая вычисляет нужную замену:

```
import re


def correct(s):

    def repl(m):
        return {'0': 'O', '1': 'I', '5': 'S'}[m.group(0)]

    return re.sub('[015]', repl, s)


print(correct("51NGAP0RE")) #=="SINGAPORE"
```

В коде выше ключи в словаре и символы в регулярном выражении дублируются. Исправляем:

```
import re


def make_correct(map_):
    chars = re.escape(''.join(map_.keys()))
    pattern = re.compile(f'[{chars}]')
    return lambda s: pattern.sub(lambda m: map_[m.group(0)], s)


correct = make_correct({'0': 'O', '1': 'I', '5': 'S'})
print(correct("51NGAP0RE")) #=="SINGAPORE"
```

**P.S.** Зачем нужен [re.escape](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape)?

Без него карта `{'0': '', '-': '', '9': ''}` даст регулярное выражение `[0-9]`, которое выбирает любые цифры, но не выбирает минус. Это не то что нужно. С `re.escape` получится выражение `[0\-9]`, выбирающее ровно три символа `0`, `-`, `9`. То что надо.

Во всех случаях когда регулярное выражение формируется программно, нужно следить за символами и комбинациями символов которые имеют специальное значение в образце. `re.escape` их экранирует чтобы не было неожиданностей.

Comment: вот с escape немного не разобрался, я так понял что он маркирует в конце слова символ \, но он как бы голый (без параметра) то есть \n это перенос строки, а без параметра зачем нужно?

Comment: Добавил **P.S.** с объяснением.

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

change_sym = {'0': 'O', '1': 'I', '5': 'S'}


def correct(data):
    for k, v in change_sym.items():
        data = re.sub(k, v, data)
    return data


print(correct('51NGAP0RE'))
```

Answer (score 1):

У тебя слишком много кода:

```py
>>> tr=str.maketrans(dict(zip('AEIO', '4310')))
>>> 'SINGAPORE'.translate(tr)
'S1NG4P0R3'
```